How should I decide on a tolerance when performing an equality comparison on floating point numbers?
Language-agnostic question, example in C# for illustrative purposes only.
I gather that comparing the equality of floating-point numbers is generally considered bad due to potential loss of precision, however there are definitely circumstances where it is absolutely necessary.
In such situations, I gather that instead of double1 == double2 for example, one should use an expression such as Math.Abs(double1 - double2) < TOLERANCE (or, in more general mathematical syntax, |d1-d2| < t).
So, how should one go about deciding on an appropriate tolerance? What factors should be taken into consideration?
Suggested duplicates here, here and here (which, by the way, are all answered by the same person) suggest that there is no general solution, which this question recognises, asking "how should I decide..." instead of just "which value should I use?". The answerer suggests that more specifics of the requirement/implementation is required to give a good answer for a value for tolerance, while this question asks about the factors one should consider while choosing a tolerance.

The question looks language-agnostic, but if you do have a specific language in mind, add the appropriate language tag.

I have marked this as a duplicate because, as the previous answers state, there is no general solution for this. In a sense, there is an answer: You must perform numerical analysis on the computations and determine what may happen in your application. However, numerical analysis is a broad field, spanning multiple college courses and academic works. It is not possible to provide a Stack Overflow answer detailing how you would go about this in general. If your question were less open-ended, we might be able to take a stab at it.

As to what factors to consider: What calculations will you perform? What ranges of numbers will they operate on? Can you analytically describe the nature of the calculations, in that they will tend to magnify error or reduce it? Are you able to compute a bound on what the final error will be? Supposing you write code that accepts all results that differ by less than that bound as equal, what will be the effect on your application when it makes mistakes because results should have been recognized as unequal but are accepted as equal because they are within that bound?

These things are generally noted within the previous answers. Another thing to consider is why you would even be doing this. What need is there for a program to decide that two unequal numbers ought to be accepted as equal? One use case where this is reasonable is testing: You have a program that ought to perform some calculations, and a test program could accept that the program is performing tolerably well if its results are close enough to results computed in some alternate way. Outside of that, there is little use for “sloppy equality“ tests. What is your use case?

@Josh Brunton, Consider how would you do this if the values were integers?  Then map each successive FP value to an integer and compare like-wise.  This handles many cases.

In C language,you could use use tolerance as follows:
1.When you use "float":
# define TOLERANCE 1e-6

2.When you use "double":
# define TOLERANCE 1e-9

It'll be right normally.That is because it is where float and double type of data will appear difference.
And in python language,you could use:
import math

math.isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0)

Importantly most, think the data it will exits when you consider how to compare them.When the data need really high performance,you could use array or linked list to store data,and compare each element of the array.
When you consider how to decide what performance should be used,maybe you should follow that the problem self.For example,if you do some normal mathematical operation,such as "/" and so on,float is sufficient.And almost all problem could use "1e-9"
Just when you have some core important problem, such as cryptography, you should use array to compare.
So,how to consider about it?
Just consider the whole project that what type of number will appeared.

Could you explain how/why you decided use 1e-6 for float and 1e-9 for double? The question is less "what values should I use" and more "how can I come to an informed decision"

Thanks for your comments, my answer has updated.

1e-6 is a little above the error that might occur in a few float operations in some cases. But it is not good as a general recommendation. For example, the relative error in 1.f/3 - .333f is about 1.7e-5, well above your bound. The cumulative rounding error in arithmetic operations in any format of any precision can range from 0 to infinity, so simply recommending a single number as a tolerance is grossly inadequate.

The precision of floating-point numbers is relative, not absolute.  (That's basically what "floating-point" means.). So you can't usefully pick a fixed tolerance like 1e-6 or 1e-9, unless you know the range of numbers you're working with (and if that range of numbers is pretty constant). But furthermore: when picking a tolerance for comparisons like this, the resolution of your floating-point format is not the only criterion: you also have to understand how much additional imprecision or uncertainty might have been introduced by your calculations.

Furthermore, the precision of double precision floating-point is (as its name suggests) roughly twice that of single precision.  So even if 1e-6 was an appropriate tolerance for some set of single-precision comparisons, the equivalent value for double precision would probably be more like 1e-12.
